# How to access an object which has been assigned inside a block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

I want to assign a value to two strings and then use them outside the block or maybe as a property in another class. But i get Null in return.

this is the code:

```
__block NSString* citySTR = nil;
__block NSString* countrySTR = nil;

[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:locationManager.location completionHandler:
 ^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
     if ([placemarks count] > 0)
     {
         citySTR = [[placemarks objectAtIndex:0] administrativeArea];
         countrySTR = [[placemarks objectAtIndex:0] country];
     }
 }];
```

When i `NSLog` citySTR and countrySTR outside the block i get `Null`.

Comment: And what about `NSLog` inside block?

Comment: @ValentinShamardin obviously i tried that and it works. It only works inside the block. but not outside.

Comment: your problem here is the _timing_. the completion block runs asynchronously, so when your start the reverse geocode location, the main thread proceeds immediately but the completion block will run much later in time.

Comment: And why did i get two negative votes?!

Comment: Why are people down-voting Dev? This is a common misunderstanding about how async calls work, and a tough concept to get in the beginning. Cut the poor guy/gal a break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to do with the values afterwards? 
If you want to set a label or call an other class method you can do it inside the block.
Another solution is to do delegation / add observer:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(somethingHappens:) name:@"notificationName" object:nil]; - this one suppose to listen do the event (called at the initialisation)
```

and this one invoking it:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notificationName" object:obj];
```

You can have citySTR and countrySTR as properties - maybe that can help

Comment: Actually what i originally did was create these two strings as properties, assign them inside the block and then use them in another class. And this is exactly what i need to do with CitySTR and countrySTR. But that doesnt work either.

Comment: Thanks this is what i just figured and was about to answer my own question. It works!

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a timing issue as when `reverseGeocodeLocation:` returns the competion handler block has not executed yet as the method is run asynchronously (I suspect by the semantics).

You probably want to call another method in the completion handler in order to use the values, however I don't know exactly what you want to do with the values so I cannot provide proper help in this area.

Comment: Ok it seems rational to me. But how would calling another method inside the completion handler help resolve this?

Comment: @devdev101 Because that's one way to say "I've just got the result you wanted", perhaps to update the UI or whatever.  Storing the values in local variables, as you are currently doing, has no benefit whatsoever.

Comment: Yeah i know and thats what i intended to do at first. This code goes in a class and i need to use this data in another class.

Comment: @devdev101 Well I think I'v answered the question; it's the difference between synchronous and asynchronous execution.

Answer (score 1):

The others have hinted around about your problem, but lets lay it out clearly.

The geocoder method reverseGeocodeLocation is an *asynchronous* call. You're saying "look up this location in the background, and once you have an answer, run the following code."

That method returns immediately, and begins processing your request in the background while your program continues to run. The reverseGeocodeLocation method has to send a request over the network, wait for a remote server (that's likely processing thousands of other requests at the same time), and then parse the response it gets back. It may take several seconds (or longer) to come back, and meanwhile your program continues to operate normally.

It's like placing an order for your main course with a waiter at a restaurant after your appetizer has arrived. If you place an order and then put your fork on your plate expecting your main course to be there instantly, you'll be disappointed. You need to wait until the waiter brings you your food after some variable amount of time. In the meantime you can continue to eat your appetizer.

If you have code that assumes that as soon as you've made the reverseGeocodeLocation call, the citySTR and countrySTR will contain values for your location, it won't be. Remember, reverseGeocodeLocation returns immediately, before your results are ready.

The reverseGeocodeLocation method saves away the completion block you give it. Once it gets an answer, it invokes that completion block code.

You should put your code to handle the list of resulting placemarks in the completion block. Your completion block code can pass messages to other objects, it can set display information in labels ,(in the current view controller) etc.